# Problemas para exibir cookies

Tags: php, cookies

Tenho um *Cookie* setado com o nome `68` e valor 68, ele aparece nas configurações de *cookies* no navegador, porem em páginas ele funciona e em outras ele simplesmente não existe

```
$id_imovel = (isset($_COOKIE[$id_imovel_form])) ? $_COOKIE[$id_imovel_form] : '' ;

if (empty($id_imovel) || $id_imovel == "") {
    setcookie($id_imovel_form, $id_imovel_form, time()+604800);
    $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => 'imóvel favoritado com sucesso');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
}
```

`$id_imovel_form` tem valor 68.

Na pagina de imóveis ele aparece corretamente:

```
foreach ($imoveis as $imoveis) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$imoveis->id_imovel]) and $_COOKIE[$imoveis->id_imovel] != ""): ?>
        <div style="background-color: #EAB346; opacity: 0.7;" onclick="favoritarImovel(<?=$imoveis->id_imovel?>,<?=$id_imovel_fav?>)" id="<?=$imoveis->id_imovel?>" class="resp"><img class="inf star" src="../img/estrela.png"></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div onclick="favoritarImovel(<?=$imoveis->id_imovel?>,<?=$id_imovel_fav?>)" id="<?=$imoveis->id_imovel?>" class="resp"><img class="inf star" src="../img/estrela.png"></div>
    <?php endif; 
}
```

Em outra pagina com o mesmo código ele não aparece, até chamando diretamente pelo nome:

```
 echo $_COOKIE['68'];
```

Comment: Exatamente valeu

Comment: Coloquei como resposta para deixar mais organizado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na função [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php) indique o caminho onde o *cookie* estará disponível. Use `/` para indicar que funcione para todo o site e não apenas o diretório onde está sendo configurado:

```
setcookie($id_imovel_form, $id_imovel_form, time()+604800, '/');
```