# O meu setcookie nao funciona

Tags: php

Boas, tenho o seguinte codigo para defenir  as minha cookies e poder utilizar noutra pagina, pelo que quando eu faço $_COOKIE[$cookie_email] na outra pagina onde quero utilizar o valor guardado dá me sempre que este valor é nulo.
mesmo pondo '/' nao funciona

```
$nomenecessario=$_GET['ref'];
$count=$_POST['nivelacessos'];
if ($conn->query("UPDATE subditos SET niveis_acesso_id='$count' WHERE 
id='$nomenecessario'") === TRUE){ 
 //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado 
 no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM subditos WHERE id='$nomenecessario' 
   LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $cookie_email = $resultado['email'];
        setcookie($cookie_email, time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = 1 day
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $nomenecessario;
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail']=$resultado['email'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioSenha']=$resultado['senha'];
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
            echo $cookie_email;
                $rer=0;
         echo "<script>irpaginafronta()</script>"; 
        }else{
            $rer=1;
                        echo "<script>irpaginah()</script>"; 

                    }


}
}
```

Comment: setcookie($cookie_email, time() + (86400 * 30)), "/");  Se indicamos "/" a cookie terá validade dentro de todo o domínio.

Comment: já tem resposta aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152224/problemas-para-exibir-cookies

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problemas para exibir cookies](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152224/problemas-para-exibir-cookies)

Comment: nenhuma das vossas respostas foi útil pois mesmo se meter '/' nao funciona

Comment: Podes informar se observado as Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor o cookie foi realmente salvo?

Comment: no seu caso faltou o "nome_do_cookie", veja resposta

Answer (score 0):

Criar um cookie com o php é muito simples, a sintaxe básica da criação é:

- setcookie(nome, valor, expira, caminho, dominio);

**Exemplo 1**

- `setcookie("nome_do_cookie", "valor_do_cookie");`

O cookie acima criado será "excluído" automaticamente, ao se fechar o Navegador

Para criar um cookie válido por 30 dias fazemos:

setcookie("nome_do_cookie", $cookie_email, time()+(86400 * 30));

> no seu caso falta `"nome_do_cookie"`

**Exemplo 2**

```
setcookie("Nome", "Music Lyrics HQ", time()+60*60*24*365, "/dir/php/", "www.dominio.com");
```

No exemplo acima criamos um cookie chamado "Nome" com o valor "Music Lyrics HQ" O cookie expira em 1 ano (60 segundos * 60 minutos * 24 horas * 365 dias) e pode ser lido apenas por arquivos no diretório "/dir/php/" no (sub-)domínio "www.dominio.com".

**Exemplo 3**

Use `/` para indicar que funcione para todo o site e não apenas o diretório onde está sendo configurado:

```
setcookie('nome_do_cookie', $cookie_email, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

**Exemplo 4**

```
setcookie("nome", "Music Lyrics HQ", time()+60*60*24*365, "/dir/php", "www.dominio.com", "1");
```

No exemplo acima criamos um cookie chamado "Nome" com o valor "Music Lyrics HQ" O cookie expira em 1 ano (60 segundos * 60 minutos * 24 horas * 365 dias) e pode ser lido apenas por arquivos no diretório "/dir/php/" no (sub-)domínio "www.dominio.com" e com uma conexão segura, pois utilizamos o valor `1` que indica que o cookie é seguro se fosse utilizado `0` ele seria inseguro.

[**setcookie**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: still not working